# What is the expected value E[X-Y] of two dependent continuous random variables with different intervals (one uniform, other exponential)?

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, convolution

I am stuck all day with the following:
Suppose I have random variable X which is exponentially distributed and random variable Y which is uniformly distributed.

$PDF_X = λexp(-λx)$ on the interval $[0,∞]$ with $E(X)=1/λ$

$PDF_Y = 1/λ$ on the interval $[0,λ]$ with $E(Y) = λ/2$

The two random variables are clearly dependent as the interval of Y is dependent on the value λ. Next to that, the intervals of the two variables do not match. I struggle hard to find $E[X-Y]$. Is it possible at all?

Apologies if this question can be found elsewhere or any mistakes.
Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: $E[X-Y]=EX-EY$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expectation is linear ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties)) in the sense that
$$
\operatorname E[aX+bY]
=a\operatorname E[X]+b\operatorname E[Y]
$$
for two random variables $X$ and $Y$ provided that the expected values of $X$ and $Y$ exist and any two constants $a$ and $b$. $X$ and $Y$ do not have to be independent or uncorrelated for the equality two hold.

We do not know if $X$ and $Y$ are dependent or independent in your example but it does not matter if we are only interested in the expected value of the difference.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You're right. I was so caught up in finding the joint PDF and dependency that I forgot such a simple rule (not the rule itself, but that it does not matter if dependent or not). Apologies.